# Appcelerator performing a manual search

Tags: android, ios, search, titanium, appcelerator

I have a search bar, table and a keypad (not the real keyboard). The keypad is manually built as a bunch of buttons with numbers at the bottom of the screen (numbers 0-9). When they click on a number, it sets the searchBar.value += which ever number they clicked. However it is not actually performing the search. Is there some kind of event I have to fire to perform the search? When I use the actual keyboard, then the search works, so I know the search bar is implemented correctly. Ideas?

Using TI SKD 6.0.4
IOS and Android OS

Answer (score 0):

TableView have a property for search view.

- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-search

You can check out the following sample code for tableView with search bar

- https://gist.github.com/MotiurRahman/853e498937074c1361ea
- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/TableView

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fire the return event for the searchbar

```
searchBar.fireEvent('return', {value: YOURVALUE})
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the filterAttribute property of the tableView, see http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-filterAttribute

Set this on your tableView:

```
tableView.filterAttribute = 'mySearchText';
```

Then set this on your tableViewRow:

```
tableViewRow.mySearchText = 'searchValue';
```

Now you're able to filter the tableView by querying your searchBar. You also want to make the `mySearchText` property dynamic to the content of your row.